# How do I fully expand the window showing the running operating system inside VirtualBox?

Tags: 12.04, windows, virtualbox, maximized

I'm running Win7 64 bit on VirtualBox and it only takes up half the screen.  How can i expand it further?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to change the screen geometry of a Virtual Box guest we need to install the virtual guest graphics driver.

> This is done by [installing the guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox).

We can then set the Virtual Box guest into the following display modes from the *View* menu of the Virtual Box Manager or by a hotkey:

- <kbd>HOST</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd>  Switch to fullscreen mode
- <kbd>HOST</kbd> +  <kbd>L</kbd>  Switch to seamless mode
- <kbd>HOST</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd>  Auto-resize guest display

Comment: I downloaded the guest and installed it on the VM.  I now have full screen.  Thx guys.